# how to print only error message in Angular

Tags: html, angular, api, types, error-handling

I'm trying to find out a way to print only the "message" part from my api call error but not sure how to get only that part so I would be really appreciated if I can get any suggestion or help.

[So this is what it show me in the network tab when there is error in the api call (pic)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yF72j.png)

```
 saveChartClick(err: any) {
    // update the chart data here
    if(!this.isTextChart && !this.isFigure && !this.isGrid){
      this.chartService.updateChart(this.chart).pipe(takeUntil(this.death$)).subscribe((updated) => {
        if(updated) {
          this.chart = updated;
          this.snackbar.open("Chart has been updated.", " ", {duration: 2500});
          this.store.dispatch(updateChart({chart: this.chart}));
        } else {

          this.snackbar.open(err.message, "close ", { duration: 2500 });
        }
      }, err => {
        this.snackbar.open(err.message, "close ", { duration: 2500 });
      })
    }
    else{
      // save the new data here
      this.store.dispatch(saveChartData({ guid: this.chart.guid, data: this.chartData }));
    }
  }
```

Right now it showing me this, which is not what I want to display since it doesn't really tell what is the error.

[Error Message it showing me right now (pic)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdawL.png)

[This is hard coded but this one example of what I want to display (pic)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8dvR.png)

The errors are handle in the backend and I can get different error message sometime so I don't want to hard code it.

Comment: What's `this.chartService.updateChart`?

Comment: i think the best way is to console the whole error object and go through it to see which item works best for you and that you want to show. 
if there isn't a good error message then on err just use IF and pass on the message you want

Comment: Hi, it's an api call (just posted that in my post). Before I add that call we only did  this.store.dispatch(updateChart({chart: this.chart})); and it's working find, it showing an error message in snackbar but It didn't show me anything when it update successfully so I thought I should added that in order to show success snackbar message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Angular's `HttpErrorResponse` object, this is how the `message` property looks like. What you want isn't

```
this.snackbar.open(err.message, "close ", { duration: 2500 });
```

but

```
this.snackbar.open(err.error.message, "close ", { duration: 2500 });
```

Or maybe, to be on the safe side (`error` can be null),

```
const errorMessage = err.error ? err.error.message : err.message;
this.snackbar.open(errorMessage, "close ", { duration: 2500 });
```

Comment: Ah ok..Not sure why const errorMessage is not working (not displaying the error message and only displaying "close" ) but err.error.message is working for me so Thank you for your help. really appreciated it.